# color theme options in emacs

Tags: emacs, colors, themes, emacs24

I am running Emacs 24 from the terminal of my mac, when I do:

```
M-x load-theme
```

Emacs asks:

```
Custom theme name:
```

I would very much like to answer that question, but I don't know what options I have! I've been searching online for over an hour. Most related answers tell me: "Now just type the theme you want." or "Here is one awesome customized theme!".

One person mentions hit TAB to autocomplete to show a list, but hitting TAB only moves my cursor forward. (Hitting TAB on my windows 7 Emacs works though).

I would appreciate any help on this matter: How do I find what themes(names) I can choose from? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OSX comes with Emacs 22 preinstalled as well. You might be running Emacs 22 from the Terminal accidentally (perhaps you just typed `emacs -nw` which would normally start Emacs 22).

Normally in Emacs 24, after `M-x load-theme` you'd get the prompt `Load custom theme:` and pressing `TAB` once at this point would show the list of all available themes.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but as I said, I did "M-x load-theme", I saw "Load custom theme" and I hit "TAB", but that didn't pring wup the list of all available themes, instead it just brought the cursor forward.

Comment: Are you certain you're running Emacs 24? Have a look at `C-h C-a`.

Comment: True. In Emacs 23 try `M-x color-theme-<TAB>`  http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Themes

Comment: The problem is fixed (sort of). <TAB> doesn't autocomplete anything when I run "emacs" from my Mac terminal. C-h C-a doesn't work there either. I have no idea why. I just downloaded emacs24 app for mac, and everything is fine with the app. Thank you both for your comments.